# How to suppress the 'PrintIn' output to the console when using Pyjulia in Python

Tags: python, julia, pyjulia

I am using Pyjulia to call Julia to solve problems in Python. However, at each time of solving the problem and getting the result, Julia would print 'found solution within...' which is output by the 'prinIn' function in the Julia package. How can I suppress such an out message? I do not want to print any message from Julia

I did not find any solution

Comment: Have you tried something simple like `pyjulia.printIn = my_function`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. That's a solution.  I gave the question to Copilot today, and the simplest solution is the same as yours. Just add two lines at the beginning of '.jl' file:


**import Base.println**

**'println(args...) = nothing'**

Comment: Hi Yanni! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please add some code to your question? When I use pyjulia, I don't encounter this text.

Comment: @Mark Thank you.  Pyjulia works well. The specific Julia package I used in my issue was what caused the text to print on the console. I have addressed the problem as my comment above.

Comment: add an answer! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just add two lines at the beginning of the main-body in your '.jl' file

```
import Base.println
println(args...) = nothing
```

Thanks to Microsoft Copilot.